# How do I define a join in ecto only if a parameter exists?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to create a function that will do some dynamic queries. There is one condition on which I want to add a join with another table, but only if a specific field is present in the `opts`

```
def list_fields(opts) do
  query =
    from f in Field,
      select: %{
        id: f.id,
        type: f.type,
        value: f.value
      }

  with query <- by_type(opts[:type], query),
       query <- by_status(opts[:status], query) do
    Repo.all(query)
  end
end
```

and I have these functions to filter down the  selection:

```
defp by_type(nil, query), do: query

defp by_type(type, query) do
  from [f] in query, where: f.type == ^type
end

defp by_status(nil, query), do: query

defp by_status(status, query) do
  from [f, d] in query, where: d.status == ^status
end
```

However the status is stored on a different table, and I don't want to add a join to it unless I have to to avoid duplication of the results.

The query with the join would look like this:

```
query =
  from f in Field,
  left_join: d in Data, on: d.field_id = f.id
  select: %{
    ...
```

How do I add this `left_join` only when the `:status` is present in `opts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the monadic magic of [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1).

```
{_, query} =
  with {status, query} when not is_nil(status) <-
          {opts[:status], by_type(opts[:type], query)},
    do: {:ok, by_status(opts[:status], query)}
Repo.all(query)
```

The trick here is if `opts[:status]` is `nil`, the first clause will return without going through `do` block and hence `by_status`.

Comment: I see, but how does that help me add the join to the query in the case that `status` is not `nil`?

Comment: You have the whole `do` block to return whatever query you want.

Comment: Oh I see, so I would need to have 2 versions of the query anyway? I was trying to find a way to avoid that. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I do not follow. You will have 1 query. Queries are composable. With `with` you’ll compose more complicated query.

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid question, but I'm learning elixir as I go, which I know isn't the best way. What I'm wondering is in which point there would I add in the `left_join` on the query

Comment: You might, for instance, modify `by_status` to be `from f in query, left_join: d in Data, on: d.field_id = f.id, where: d.status == ^status`.